# Expo app icon instead of my app icon - react native

Tags: javascript, android, json, react-native

SDK Version: 41.0.0
Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): android
Add the appropriate “Tag” based on what Expo library you have a question on.
Hi Guys,

I’m trying to build a standalone app (android) with expo but I get an apk with the expo icon instead of my specified icon.

im using react native and proplem in android ,i didnt setup ios, work in vscode i dont work with android studio i don't have gradle

here’s my app.json

```
{
    "expo": {
      "name": "جونت",
      "description": "a platform where those who drive and deliver can connect with riders",
      "slug": "jaunt",
      "privacy": "public",
      "platforms": [
        "ios",
        "android"
      ],
      "notification": {
        "icon": "./assets/images/logo96x96.png"
      },
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "orientation": "portrait",
      "icon": "./assets/images/logo1024x1024.png",
      "splash": {
        "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
        "resizeMode": "cover",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "updates": {
        "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
      },
      "assetBundlePatterns": [
        "**/*"
      ],
      "packagerOpts": {
        "config": "metro.config.js"
      },
      "ios": {
        "supportsTablet": true,
        "usesAppleSignIn": true,
        "bundleIdentifier": "com.binsaleh.jaunt",
        "infoPlist": {
          "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription": "يستخدم هذا التطبيق إمكانية الوصول دائمًا إلى الموقع في الخلفية لتحسين عمليات الالتقاط والإنزال ودعم العملاء وغرض السلامة.",
          "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription": "يستخدم هذا التطبيق إمكانية الوصول دائمًا إلى الموقع في الخلفية لتحسين عمليات الالتقاط والإنزال ودعم العملاء وغرض السلامة.",
          "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "يستخدم هذا التطبيق الموقع للعثور على سيارات الأجرة القريبة منك.",
          "NSCameraUsageDescription": "يستخدم هذا التطبيق الكاميرا لالتقاط صورة ملفك الشخصي.",
          "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "يستخدم هذا التطبيق مكتبة الصور لتحميل صورة ملفك الشخصي.",
          "NSUserTrackingUsageDescription": "سيتتبع هذا التطبيق موقعك بشكل مستمر وفي الخلفية. سيتم استخدام هذه البيانات لإظهار موضع سيارتك للعميل في الوقت الفعلي ، مما سيساعد في تحسين عمليات الالتقاط والإنزال ، وكذلك زيادة السرعة والأمان في العملية.",
          "ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption":false,
          "UIBackgroundModes": [
            "audio",
            "location",
            "fetch"
          ]
        },
        "config": {
          "googleMapsApiKey": "AIzaSyCokG9nDL49x3u-JWWL4YE5ngqz34fHPW0"
        },
        "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist",
        "buildNumber": "1.0.0"
      },
      "android": {
        "package": "com.binsaleh.jaunt",
        "versionCode": 1,
        "permissions": [
          "CAMERA",
          "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
          "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
          "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
          "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
          "CAMERA_ROLL",
          "FOREGROUND_SERVICE",
          "ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"
        ],
        "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
        "config": {
          "googleMaps": {
            "apiKey": "AIzaSyCokG9nDL49x3u-JWWL4YE5ngqz34fHPW0"
          }
        },
        "useNextNotificationsApi": true
      },
      "facebookScheme": "fb245228120355609",
      "facebookAppId": "245228120355609",
      "facebookDisplayName": "jaunt"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE: The solution below applies for bare workflow**

It seems like Expo does not update the Android build after changes in app.json. I have to do this to update the app with my own icons:

- Delete `./android` (the Android build directory autogenerated by Expo)
- run `expo run:android` again

Now the correct Android app icons an splash image should appear.
For any changes to icons or background color you have to run the steps through again.

It's a little bit frustrating that the [Expo app icon guide](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/app-icons/) does not mention that their guide does not work for bare workflows. I tried around a bit of time by changing paths, changing image sizes, delete and re-install the node_modules,...

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, just remember to check the diff between files because if made changes on any native code they will be override.

Comment: Thx. A lot of time wasted trying to figure this out.